# mailserver log filtering

Tags: perl, postfix-mta

I've got multi-GB mailserver log file and a list of ~350k messages ID.
I want to pull out from the big log file rows with IDs from the long list... and I want it faster than it is now...
Currently I do it in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

#opening file with the list - over 350k unique ID
open ID, maillog_id;
@lista_id = <ID>;
close ID;
chomp @lista_id;

open LOG, maillog;
# while - foreach would cause out of memory
while ( <LOG> ) {
        $wiersz = $_;
        my @wiersz_split = split ( ' ' , $wiersz );
        #
        foreach ( @lista_id ) {
          $id   = $_;
          # ID in maillog is 6th column
          if ( $wiersz_split[5] eq $id)  {
            # print whole row when matched - can be STDOUT or file or anything
            print "@wiersz_split\n";
          }
        }
}
close LOG;
```

It works but it is slow... Every line from log is taken into comparison with list of ID.
Should I use database and perform a kind of join? Or compare substrings?

There are a lot of tools for log analyse - e.g. pflogsumm... but it just summarizes. E.g. I could use

```
grep -c "status=sent" maillog
```

It would be fast but useless and I would use it AFTER filtering my log file... the same is for pflogsumm etc. - just increasing variables.

Any suggestions?

-------------------- UPDATE -------------------

thank you Dallaylaen,
I succeded with this (instead internal foreach on `@lista_id`):

```
if ( exists $lista_id_hash{$wiersz_split[5]} ) { print "$wiersz"; }
```

where `%lista_id_hash` is a hash table where keys are items taken from my ID list. It works superfast.
Processing 4,6 GB log file with >350k IDs takes less than 1 minute to filter interesting logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash.

```
my %known;
$known{$_} = 1 for @lista_id;
# ...
while (<>) {
    # ... determine id
    if ($known{$id}) {
         # process line
    };
};
```

P.S. If your log is THAT big, you're probably better off with splitting it according to e.g. last two letters of $id into 256 (or 36**2?) smaller files. Something like a poor man's MapReduce. The number of IDs to store in memory at a time will also be reduced (i.e. when you're processing maillog.split.cf, you should only keep IDs ending in "cf" in hash).

Comment: Wanted offer similar approach, only using map: `my %known = map {$_ => 1} @lista_id;`

Comment: @wk: `map` or `for` are equivalent here, but a more careful approach would be to skip `@lista_id` altogether and to populate `%known` inside `while(<ID>)` loop -- this could reduce memory usage a bit.